# CamanJS filters unresponsive to button clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, camanjs

I am using following code to apply filters on button click

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<a href="#" id="vig">Vignette</a>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/camanjs/3.2/caman.full.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
var vig = $('#vig');

vig.on('click', function(e){
alert("Button Clicked");
Caman("image.jpg", "#canvas", function(){
this
    .vignette(300, 60)
    .render();
});
});
</script>
```

When I click on button the button, I get the alert but the camanJS filter does not do anything. If I put the code of filter outside the button click function it works perfectly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Caman("image.jpg", "#canvas", function(){
this
    .vignette(300, 60)
    .render();
});
</script>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Does the canvas initialize with the base image after the button is clicked? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No canvas does not initialize with base image and there is no error in console. All I get is 200 OK and 304 Not Modified. Clicking on button does not result in any error in console either.